# What is 'cat' param used for in TreeBagger method

Tags: matlab

I am following the tutorial and am trying to implement TreeBagger Method. I have a question since I cannot understand part of the code.

```
b = TreeBagger(nTrees,X,Y,'oobpred','on','cat',6,'minleaf',leaf(ii));
```

Can anyone tell me what 'cat' is and the number 6 please?

Answer (score 1):

The constructor for TreeBagger:

```
%   In addition to the optional arguments above, this method accepts all
%   optional CLASSREGTREE arguments with the exception of 'minparent'.
%   Refer to the documentation for CLASSREGTREE for more detail.
```

'cat' is not one of the valid input pairs for TreeBagger, so it must be an input for CLASSREGTREE. Looking at the input pairs for classregtree, the only input pair close to 'cat' is 'categorical,' which says:

```
%      'categorical' Vector of indices of the columns of X that are to be
%                   treated as unordered categorical variables
```

If you look at statgetargs.m, specifically this line:

```
i = strmatch(lower(pname),pnames);
```

It will allow any arguments as long as the first portion is spelled correctly. pnames will contain a cell array of valid strings (one of them will be 'categorical') while pname will contain a string to compare pnames with (eventually, this will contain 'cat'). If you enter only the first portion of the input string, it will still work. I.e. for me this works:

```
EDU>> a = TreeBagger(nTrees,X,Y,'oobpr','on','cat',6,'minle',leaf(ii));
EDU>> b = TreeBagger(nTrees,X,Y,'oobpred','on','cat',6,'minleaf',leaf(ii));
EDU>> isequal(a,b)

ans =

     1
```

It doesn't work if 'cat' is changed because it stores 'cat' explicitly as it's spelled under TreeArgs. Regardless, 'cat' is being treated as 'categorical' for classregtree.

Answer (score 0):

`cat` is being treated as an abbreviation of the `categorical` input parameter of `classregtree`, and it specifies that the sixth variable in `X` should be treated as categorical.